# Find a one year date from now in Python/Pandas with approximations

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, dataframe

I have a df pandas with in column just a 'Price' and in index dates. I want to find a new column called 'Aprox' with inside

```
 aprox. = price of today - price of one year ago (or closest date from a year ago) - 
price in one year (again take aprox if exact one year price don't exist)
 for example   
 aprox. 2019-04-30 = 8 -4 -10 = -6 = aprox. 2019-04-30
                                            - aprox. 2018-01-31 - aprox.2020-07-30
```

To be honest I am a bit strugling with that...

```
ex. [in]:      Price
2018-01-31       4  
2019-04-30       8 
2020-07-30       10   
2020-10-31       9  
2021-01-31       14   
2021-04-30       150
2021-07-30       20
2022-10-31       14

   [out]:      Price    aprox.
2018-01-31       4  
2019-04-30       8       -6  ((8-4-10) = -6) since there is no 2018-04-30 
2020-07-30       10      -12 (10-14-8)
2020-10-31       9       ...
2021-01-31       14      ...
2021-04-30       150
2021-07-30       20
2022-10-31       14
```

I am strugling very much with that... even more with the approx.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to do, but maybe this is what you want:

```
import pandas

def last_year(x):
    """
    Return date from a year ago.
    """
    return x - pandas.DateOffset(years=1)

# Simulate the data you provided in example
dt_str = ['2018-01-31', '2019-04-30', '2020-07-30', '2020-10-31',
          '2021-01-31', '2021-04-30', '2021-07-30', '2022-10-31']
dates = [pandas.Timestamp(x) for x in dt_str]
df = pandas.DataFrame([4, 8, 10, 9, 14, 150, 20, 14], columns=['Price'], index=dates)

# This is the code that does the work
for dt, value in df['Price'].iteritems():
    df.loc[dt, 'approx'] = value - df['Price'].asof(last_year(dt))
```

This gave me the following results:

```
In [147]: df
Out[147]:
              Price  approx
2018-01-31      4     NaN
2019-04-30      8     4.0
2020-07-30     10     2.0
2020-10-31      9     1.0
2021-01-31     14     6.0
2021-04-30    150   142.0
2021-07-30     20    10.0
2022-10-31     14    -6.0
```

The bottom line is that for this type of operation you can't just use the `apply` operation since you need both the index and the value.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply @aquil.abdullah ! It is not exactly what I am looking for. For example for 2019-04-30, 'approx' column should give back the Price for 2019-04-30 (here 8) MINUS the price one year before MINUS the price one year after. If there is no price for an exact year before or after in my dataset, I just want to take the closest price/date from this one year, so here the price of 2020-07-30 and 2018-01-31. 

    The calculus should be 8 - 4 - 10 = - 6